# Checkboxlist not retaining selection after postback in IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery, checkboxlist

Platform: ASP.Net 2.0

I have multiple checkboxlist controls on a webpage. Along with that i have the same number of buttons on that page. Initially all the checkboxlist controls are hidden. When user clicks on a button, corresponding checkboxlist controls gets visible making others hidden and allows user to select the options.

On postback, if user clicks on the same button again, the corresponding checkboxlist gets visible but the item selection is not retained. However, this happens only in IE. This works fine in FireFox. I am using JQuery to toggle the visibility of checkboxlist.

I guess the problem is because i am toggling the visibility of checkboxlist which IE doesnt seem to like. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: You may want to consider that it might be Firefox putting the values back it from it's form cache, and both are behaving the same in terms of client/server behavior.

Comment: could be. I removed the toggle thing and made them being displayed all the time. still the selection disappears.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound totally weird but after struggling for a day, i changed the rendering sequence of the div. To my surprise, it started working fine.